# Return copies of private data rather than references

Tags: java, reference

In the astonishing book "Java the Good Parts" the author gives some code that returns a copy of an object within its getter method (to be used with an well-encapsulated field) and then states:

> This approach, which tries to return copies of private data
>   rather than references to that private data, is generally a good idea

Why is that so? I thought a goal of encapsulation was to make sure that nobody can actually alter private members. So why would I write something like this

```
private someType fieldName = new someType(); 

...
```

while defining its getter like this (assuming that there is some sort of copy-constructor)

```
someType getSomething() 
{
return new someType(fieldName); 
}
```

From what I know now, I mean before you guys pop in is:

that this makes sense in so far that it services garbage collection, since this approach doesn't maintain references to the actual object.

it also may be understandable from an inner-class perspective, from which any method could alter any field accesable via the reference.

But I don't suspect the two reasons for doing so to be what's really beyond that issue.

Comment: The garbage collection aspect is debatable I think: it might clean up that particular reference sooner but it also causes a GC to occur more often. The main purpose is probably immutability.

Answer (score 20):

When types are mutable, it's *often* useful to return a copy so that a client can't fundamentally modify your data, at least without telling you about it. Consider:

```
public class Person {
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        // Do some validation, e.g. that it's after 1800
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

That looks okay, right? But what about:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setDateOfBirth(new Date()); // Now... fine.
// Aha! Modify the Date to a very long time ago. Now anyone else
// using the Person will be messed up...
person.getDateOfBirth().setTime(Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

If `getDateOfBirth` returns a copy instead, then any changes the caller makes to the `Date` object that the return value refers to will be irrelevant to anyone else. The `Person` object is still valid, because it only has a valid date. Of course, this should be documented so that whoever wrote the above code would *expect* it not to affect the `Person` object, due to a copy being returned.

A *better* solution than all of this copying is to favour immutable types, however - when you've got a reference to an immutable object, you can share that as widely as you like, knowing that no-one can change its state under your feet.

Comment: Thanks for the note on immutability. I wasn't paying attention to the fact that this issue only arises when the mutability-question is answered with yes.

Comment: There are uses for returning the reference instead of a copy, but considering this is C#, that's what properties are for. `person.DateOfBirth.setTime(...)` makes more sense.

Comment: @Cole: When you say "considering this is C#" - this question is about Java, not C#.

Comment: It might be wise to suggest using a library which offers immutable date objects over the default dates in Java - I'm sure I don't have to convince _you_ why it might be beneficial but your erm.. 'conflict of interest' in suggesting a library that gives you immutable date objects as a solution for dates shouldn't prevent you from mentioning it here in my opinion - after the bigger answer for the bigger question of course.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I'm not sure what conflict of interest you're thinking of (given that this is Java) - I haven't mentioned any libraries because they would only address the example I happened to give... they're not particularly relevant to the general question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Correct. My mistake. Your code is valid C# also (if there was a `Date` class instead of `DateTime`). I almost never work with Java, so seeing the code made me think C#

Answer (score 7):

The idea is that the getter lets you view the state of the object without being able to modify it (since you'll be modifying a copy, and not the original).

If you call :

```
someType property = someObj.getSomething();
```

and then

```
property.setSomeSubProperty(someValue);
```

This would only change the copy of `someType`, and not the original `someType` stored within `someObj`.

If the class that contains the `getSomething()` method is mutable, it may have a `setSomething(someType value)` method, and using that method would be the acceptable way to modify that property.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. But why would I do this while the field is already private? To me this looks like extra work. Is it just a practice of clean code?

Comment: @AndrewTobey It doesn't matter if the field is private. The getter is public, and if you don't return a copy in the getter, it gives you a reference to the field, which you can modify.

Comment: gotcha. Talking about access in the sense of access modifiers means direct, whereas methods mean indirect access. So the point is eventually to go without the reference which offers indirect access!?

Answer (score 2):

Good answers already come up, but let me come up with other examples and references

Best source to explain would be a *Effective Java* by Josh Bloch. There are at least 2 chapters about immutability and defensive copies.

To make it short: 
In Java you pass everything by a reference (I know that it's oversimplified, but that's not the point) and many classes are mutable. Hence direct assignment of private field with external object is not really safe, as value underneath can change at any point of time from outside of the object, breaking the encapsulation.

Accessor methods are the essence of breaking the encapsulation. In the most common implementation, you  just make the field public and, as mentioned above, you allow anyone to change underlying objects, if they allow to do so. Best example are collections IMHO. If you return any default Java collection, anyone can add something to it, remove element or even purge it. If your logic depends on the state or you are writing multithreaded app it's the easiest way to get a race condition, something we really don't want to have.

So a good practice is either

- returning the deep copy of an object (e.g. Guava copy collection methods)
- returning a view on a object (e.g. Collections class and its methods)
- using immutable objects (easiest of 'em all)
- cloning or other funky business

Each of those have some cost related to them. Copying/cloning takes time and memory. Views are not fully safe, as underlying implementation may change at any point of time, immutable objects does not allow modification and are hard to implement in legacy systems, etc It's up to you to find balance, but we're always happy to help :)

Last thing, it's also a good practice to do a defensive copy in constructor/setter of passed in mutable parameter, for exactly same reason. If someone would add elements to collection that we've made final in constructor, that would be quite stupid, c's we're not preserving state, which we obviously wanted. So again, in constructor don't do just a simple initialization if you're not controlling what has been passed in (and even if  you do, it may be a good idea to copy)

I prefer collections as an example, as they are easier to reason on how to make copy/how they change, however StringBuilder and Date mentioned in other answers, really show that it's not only issue of collections. So best answer is: **Remember, final is your best friend. Use it often, from the very beginning, and never trust mutable strangers!**

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no such thing as "private data", there is in reality only data that you can't reach and data you can't change.

Suppose that fieldName is defined as StringBuilder fieldName.  There's nothing you can do to a StringBuilder that will prevent someone that has access to it from modifying it.  On the other hand, if it is defined as string fieldName, then (absent some truly evil reflection) there is no chance of someone else changing it.

So, it's an expensive substitute for immutability. Better yet is to use a wrapper that only allows access to the properties and actions you want to make available.

Comment: thx. your comment should be the footnote for any literature discussing access modifiers. The lectures, and also all the books I have read to this day pictured it as if "private" is everything to care about.

Comment: A lot of people misunderstand modifiers -- modifiers are there to help define areas of concern, not security and definitely not mutability.